# jQuery add class is not working 

Tags: jquery, syntax

Hey ya'll I have this code here and it suppose to add the class name "cboxElement"

```
$(".wpcart_gallery a:first").addClass("cboxElement");
```

but it does not work.

I have the proper Jquery file in my header, I have surrounded this in `jQuery('document').ready(function($){......});` and it works for all my other Jquery but the add class call.

here is what I am trying to add the class to...

```
<div class="wpcart_gallery" style="text-align:center; padding-top:5px;">
<a class="thickbox" href="DSC_0037.jpg" rev="DSC_0037.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Anybody know why this isnt working? I am new to jquery

this is also in wordpress hence the `jQuery('document')`

Comment: What does `not work :(` mean? Check to see if the selector is actually selecting something.

Comment: The css properties are probably getting overriden.

Comment: should work - http://jsfiddle.net/3Fbnv/1/

Comment: error console says `TypeError: $ is not a function

$(".wpcart_gallery a:first").addClass("cboxElement");`

Comment: Try using "jQuery" instead of "$" in the console then

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".wpcart_gallery a:first").addClass("cboxElement");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Zoltran noted and demonstrated on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Fbnv/1), the code you listed works in at least some situations.  Is it possible that the div element that you are adding the class to does not yet exist when .ready() executes?  I suggest adding this line:

```
console.log("container:", $(".wpcart_gallery"), "link:", $(".wpcart_gallery a:first"));
```

after your .addClass() code and then viewing the debug console (e.g. [Chrome's web inspector](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/)).  Do you see your elements or undefined?  If you see your undefined than it's quite possible that your .addClass() code is running before the element upon which it acts is ready.  If you do get your elements, it's possible that your style (or some other part of the code) is overwriting / undoing your change.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your selector is returning more than one or null. There might be other elements in your html with the same selectors. As Zoltan indicated, it should work. Try to print to consol.log($(".wpcart_gallery a:first")); in firefox or chrome and debug it with firebug that might give you some indication where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this mate.....

```
jQuery('document').ready(function($){

  jQuery(".wpcart_gallery a:first").addClass('cboxElement');

});
```